# How can I make guests come in my second home?

Tags: pc, the-sims-3

I bought a second home for my sim and I can't figure out how to allow a guest in! She just stands in the front door talking on the cellphone. I tried actions that usually draw her attention such as inviting guests to have lunch but it's not working.

Other things I've tried so far:

- Delete all doors and place new ones, in case the main door was wrongly placed.
- Change door lock options. It's only available for the first house.

Comment: When you say you bought a second home, you mean two houses on the same lot?

Answer (score 1):

You have to "move to this lot", (by clicking the ricon in map view), otherwise all your visitors will go to the main residence.